# Let's get critical: May 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Audio-Video Production Stack Exchange](http://avp.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://video.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/7594/sound-what-are-the-options-for-vst-production

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)
- https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/7578/what-instruments-are-these

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/7645/first-steps-to-improve-a-laptop-recording

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)
- https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/7668/ableton-how-do-i-automatically-make-a-clip-on-beat

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/7686/how-can-i-compress-my-bassline-like-the-linked-boris-brejcha-track

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/7750/will-low-output-volume-affect-the-quality-of-the-sound

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)
- https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/7576/how-to-create-cue-sheet-for-long-wav-file

  **Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)
- https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/7532/best-software-to-record-voice-synchronously-with-a-video-i-e-dubbing

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Recommended Encoding for VHS to Digital to be Followed by Post Processing](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/7627/recommended-encoding-for-vhs-to-digital-to-be-followed-by-post-processing)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/7674/how-to-set-follow-action-in-thirtytwos-ableton-live

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

Answer (score 1):

In general, I found that questions offered up for evaluation were what I would consider satisfactory.

Of the couple that seemed like good canonical questions (one about converting VHS to Digital comes to mind, and had good answers), they did not show up in a google search.  Somewhat disheartening there...

There were another few that were very localized.  I don't necessarily think too localized for the site (though that may be debatable in a meta post), but questions on the order of "What is," or "How do I recreate this youtube example?"

I would guess that those are likely impossible to google for.  They may also be quite difficult to search AVP for!  They probably ought to be the subject of a meta post to discuss how best to title/tag them for searchability, both within the site and without.